# Get user name with Youtube Data API 3.0

Tags: javascript, api, youtube-api

Hi I'm trying to get the youtube  user name and the thumbnail with a youtube app. I´m using the v3.0 and the javascript library.
I'm following this example and docs:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs

I don't have problems with the autentication but I don't know how to get de user name and image.
Somebody knows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [channels->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) with "part=id & mine=true"

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

[Id](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#id) is the channel's ID.

You can get the channel's title from response under [snippet.title](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#snippet.title). This is what you need as usernames are not useful anymore.

From [snippet.thumbnails.(key)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#snippet.thumbnails.%28key%29), you can pick the default, medium or high resolution thumbnail, and get it's width, height and URL.

This is what you are looking for to greet, but if you want to go deeper you can check if that [account is linked](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#status.isLinked) with Google+ and use [googleplususerid](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.googlePlusUserId) to retrieve more information via Google+ API.

Comment: can't use API key for a request which require authentication

Comment: Thanks for the `mine=true` tip.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&mine=true&access_token = [YOUR TOKEN]

YOU MUST get Oauth code and exchange it for Access Token, to  :( complex to give you full answer HERE

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I had to modify my requests to make it work with authentication (otherwise I kept getting a "dailyLimitExceededUnreg" error in the response):

- Don't include the "key={YOUR_API_KEY}" in the URL.
- Instead, add a HTTP header "Authorization: Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}"